# What is expense growth in this diagram?

Tags: expenses

Taken from Standard Chartered's 2010 full year web print final
[image: Standard charted 2010 annual report]

My questions are:

1) What are the 'C's referring to? Eg. c.400 c.350 etc.

2) What are WB and CB?

3) What's BAU?

4) Why is Regulatory settlements in blue? Is it negative or attributed to 2010?

5) What does incremental investment refer to?

6) What does FX expense refer to?

Original file here: http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/stanchar/1204253106x0x446956/A753C00F-67B0-4007-A36F-EDC9B148EAE7/Full_Year_2010_webPrint_Final.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "c." is probably circa, or "about."  Regulatory settlements is in blue because it's negative; the amount is in parentheses, which indicates a loss.

WB and CB might be wholesale banking and commercial banking?

BAU probably means "business as usual" or things that don't directly apply to the project.

Incremental investment is the additional cash a company puts towards its long-term capital assets.

FX is probably foreign exchange.